# Undefined index: cash in pset7 at portfolio.php

Tags: cs50

I'm getting the following error which doesn't allow me to display the portfolio correctly. Could anyone help me to find the issue?

This is the error message: Undefined index: cash in /home/ubuntu/workspace/pset7/views/portfolio.php on line 37

This is line 37:

```
<tr> <td colspan="4">CASH</td> <?php print("<td>{$_SESSION["cash"]}</td>"); ?> </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're calling `session_start()` and you assigned something to `$_SESSION["cash"]` previously. It is good practice to first check if it's set before trying to use it:

```
<?php if( isset($_SESSION["cash"]) ){ ?>
  <tr><td colspan="4">CASH</td><td><?= $_SESSION["cash"] ?></td></tr>
<?php } else { ?>
  <tr><td colspan="5">Unknown CASH amount</td></tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still having some issues, but that definitely helped